# Skype corrupted on Windows, not showing Login menu option

Tags: windows-7, skype

I had installed Skype on Windows 7 and it was working fine for a while. Recently, I downloaded some other utility for Windows, and it required the MS VC runtime redistributable, which I also installed and ran. It looks like that has caused Skype to stop working. Now when I run Skype, it does not even show me the Login option under the Skype menu.

[image: http://imgur.com/DzDAsyT]

Earlier when it was working, when I clicked the "Skype" menu shown in the image above, it used to drop down the "Login" or "Connect" menu option, and which, when clicked, would pop up a dialog in which I could login to Skype. Now that Skype menu only shows the "Close" menu option when I click it. Hence no way at all to login.

I uninstalled and reinstalled Skype a couple of times via Control Panel, but there is no change.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to uninstall using a third-party tool, such as [Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and [Geek Uninstaller](http://www.geekuninstaller.com/download). Remove all registry and files that may left behind by the original uninstaller (these two programs help to do that for your).

Comment: Tried Revo Uninstaller. Used it to remove Skype Click to Call and then Skype. Then reinstalled Skype. Still gives the same problem. No login menu shows. I had used the Moderate option of Revo Uninstaller, also purpose did not choose to delete the callto and tel registry keys, since I was not sure that was the right thing to do. Will check some more tomorrow, and then post again here. Thanks to all who replied.

Comment: I re-ran Revo Uninstaller with the highest option (the one shown on its screen below "Moderate"). Here is a screenshot of what it showed after the deep scan of the registry and hard drive, when it searched for any remaining items related to the Skype that was uninstalled: http://imgur.com/2ux0o6e  I'd appreciate any further advice on what to do next; e.g. should I remove some or all of those registry entries that show in the screenshot, using Revo Uninstaller?

Comment: @VasudevRam yes, you can remove them

Comment: I did that. Then reinstalled Skype. It is now working normally. Thanks a lot to all who replied and helped.